# Need help to make single character with multiple accents

Tags: fonts, fontsize, accents, superscripts, variable

I need to fix the character with two accent's for (**Caps,SmallCaps, Italic, Bold and various fontsize character's**). But output clashing with accent characters with respect to character height. (Could you please give a solution coding without clashing the accent's at any font size will come)

My MWE is

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}

\parindent0pt
\pagestyle{empty}


\makeatletter

\newlength\twoaccsep
\setlength{\twoaccsep}{-0.8ex}

\def\twoacc[#1|#2]{\leavevmode{\setbox1=\hbox{{#1{}}}%
                     \setbox2=\hbox{{#2{}}}%
                     \dimen0=\ifdim\wd1>\wd2\wd1\else\wd2\fi%
                     \dimen1=\ht2\advance\dimen1by\twoaccsep%
                     \setbox1=\hbox to1\dimen0{\hss#1{}\hss}%
                     \rlap{\raise1\dimen1\box1}%
                     \hbox to1\dimen0{\hss#2\hss}}%
                     }%

\makeatother

\def\INTtildeacute#1{\twoacc[\'|\~{#1}]\ }% grave over macron



\INTtildeacute{A}\INTtildeacute{B}\INTtildeacute{C}\INTtildeacute{D}\INTtildeacute{E}\INTtildeacute{F}\INTtildeacute{G}\INTtildeacute{H}\INTtildeacute{I}\INTtildeacute{J}\INTtildeacute{K}\INTtildeacute{L}\INTtildeacute{M}\INTtildeacute{N}\INTtildeacute{O}\INTtildeacute{P}\INTtildeacute{Q}\INTtildeacute{R}\INTtildeacute{S}\INTtildeacute{T}\INTtildeacute{U}\INTtildeacute{V}\INTtildeacute{W}\INTtildeacute{X}\INTtildeacute{Y}\INTtildeacute{Z}

\textit{\INTtildeacute{A}\INTtildeacute{B}\INTtildeacute{C}\INTtildeacute{D}\INTtildeacute{E}\INTtildeacute{F}\INTtildeacute{G}\INTtildeacute{H}\INTtildeacute{I}\INTtildeacute{J}\INTtildeacute{K}\INTtildeacute{L}\INTtildeacute{M}\INTtildeacute{N}\INTtildeacute{O}\INTtildeacute{P}\INTtildeacute{Q}\INTtildeacute{R}\INTtildeacute{S}\INTtildeacute{T}\INTtildeacute{U}\INTtildeacute{V}\INTtildeacute{W}\INTtildeacute{X}\INTtildeacute{Y}\INTtildeacute{Z}}\vspace*{20pt}

\INTtildeacute{a}\INTtildeacute{b}\INTtildeacute{c}\INTtildeacute{d}\INTtildeacute{e}\INTtildeacute{f}\INTtildeacute{g}\INTtildeacute{h}\INTtildeacute{i}\INTtildeacute{j}\INTtildeacute{k}\INTtildeacute{l}\INTtildeacute{m}\INTtildeacute{n}\INTtildeacute{o}\INTtildeacute{p}\INTtildeacute{q}\INTtildeacute{r}\INTtildeacute{s}\INTtildeacute{t}\INTtildeacute{u}\INTtildeacute{v}\INTtildeacute{w}\INTtildeacute{x}\INTtildeacute{y}\INTtildeacute{z}

\textit{\INTtildeacute{a}\INTtildeacute{b}\INTtildeacute{c}\INTtildeacute{d}\INTtildeacute{e}\INTtildeacute{f}\INTtildeacute{g}\INTtildeacute{h}\INTtildeacute{i}\INTtildeacute{j}\INTtildeacute{k}\INTtildeacute{l}\INTtildeacute{m}\INTtildeacute{n}\INTtildeacute{o}\INTtildeacute{p}\INTtildeacute{q}\INTtildeacute{r}\INTtildeacute{s}\INTtildeacute{t}\INTtildeacute{u}\INTtildeacute{v}\INTtildeacute{w}\INTtildeacute{x}\INTtildeacute{y}\INTtildeacute{z}}\vspace*{20pt}


{Normalsize\\
\ensuremath{\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upiota}}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upkappa}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\uptheta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upvartheta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upepsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upomega}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upphi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upvarphi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\uppi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upvarpi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upzeta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upchi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upsigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upalpha}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upbeta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upgamma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\updelta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varepsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\lambda}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\mu}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\nu}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\xi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\rho}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varrho}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varsigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\tau}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\psi}}

\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varGamma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varDelta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varTheta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varLambda}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varXi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varPi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varSigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varUpsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varPhi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varPsi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varOmega}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Gamma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Delta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Theta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Xi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Pi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Sigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Upsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Phi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Psi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Omega}}\par}\vspace*{20pt}

{\footnotesize
Footnotesize\\
\INTtildeacute{A}\INTtildeacute{B}\INTtildeacute{C}\INTtildeacute{D}\INTtildeacute{E}\INTtildeacute{F}\INTtildeacute{G}\INTtildeacute{H}\INTtildeacute{I}\INTtildeacute{J}\INTtildeacute{K}\INTtildeacute{L}\INTtildeacute{M}\INTtildeacute{N}\INTtildeacute{O}\INTtildeacute{P}\INTtildeacute{Q}\INTtildeacute{R}\INTtildeacute{S}\INTtildeacute{T}\INTtildeacute{U}\INTtildeacute{V}\INTtildeacute{W}\INTtildeacute{X}\INTtildeacute{Y}\INTtildeacute{Z}

\textit{\INTtildeacute{A}\INTtildeacute{B}\INTtildeacute{C}\INTtildeacute{D}\INTtildeacute{E}\INTtildeacute{F}\INTtildeacute{G}\INTtildeacute{H}\INTtildeacute{I}\INTtildeacute{J}\INTtildeacute{K}\INTtildeacute{L}\INTtildeacute{M}\INTtildeacute{N}\INTtildeacute{O}\INTtildeacute{P}\INTtildeacute{Q}\INTtildeacute{R}\INTtildeacute{S}\INTtildeacute{T}\INTtildeacute{U}\INTtildeacute{V}\INTtildeacute{W}\INTtildeacute{X}\INTtildeacute{Y}\INTtildeacute{Z}}\vspace*{20pt}

\INTtildeacute{a}\INTtildeacute{b}\INTtildeacute{c}\INTtildeacute{d}\INTtildeacute{e}\INTtildeacute{f}\INTtildeacute{g}\INTtildeacute{h}\INTtildeacute{i}\INTtildeacute{j}\INTtildeacute{k}\INTtildeacute{l}\INTtildeacute{m}\INTtildeacute{n}\INTtildeacute{o}\INTtildeacute{p}\INTtildeacute{q}\INTtildeacute{r}\INTtildeacute{s}\INTtildeacute{t}\INTtildeacute{u}\INTtildeacute{v}\INTtildeacute{w}\INTtildeacute{x}\INTtildeacute{y}\INTtildeacute{z}

\textit{\INTtildeacute{a}\INTtildeacute{b}\INTtildeacute{c}\INTtildeacute{d}\INTtildeacute{e}\INTtildeacute{f}\INTtildeacute{g}\INTtildeacute{h}\INTtildeacute{i}\INTtildeacute{j}\INTtildeacute{k}\INTtildeacute{l}\INTtildeacute{m}\INTtildeacute{n}\INTtildeacute{o}\INTtildeacute{p}\INTtildeacute{q}\INTtildeacute{r}\INTtildeacute{s}\INTtildeacute{t}\INTtildeacute{u}\INTtildeacute{v}\INTtildeacute{w}\INTtildeacute{x}\INTtildeacute{y}\INTtildeacute{z}}\par}\vspace*{20pt}


{\footnotesize:Footnotesize\\
\ensuremath{\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upiota}}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upkappa}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\uptheta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upvartheta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upepsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upomega}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upphi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upvarphi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\uppi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upvarpi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upzeta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upchi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upsigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upalpha}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upbeta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upgamma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\updelta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varepsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\lambda}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\mu}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\nu}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\xi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\rho}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varrho}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varsigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\tau}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\upsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\psi}}

\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varGamma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varDelta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varTheta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varLambda}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varXi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varPi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varSigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varUpsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varPhi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varPsi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\varOmega}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Gamma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Delta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Theta}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Lambda}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Xi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Pi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Sigma}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Upsilon}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Phi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Psi}}\INTtildeacute{\ensuremath{\Omega}}\par}



\end{document}
```

Comment: While Latin Modern is a good attempt, its support for combining characters is unfortunately far from perfect. If I try Libertinus Serif, for instance, then `\'{\~a}}` works well in most instances. Anyway, you can't expect that your `\INTtildeacute` works in math mode.

Comment: I endorse what @egreg wrote, above comment. The Libertinus Serif font looks good, has a large character set, and does some things better than Latin Modern Roman. If you have libertinus-fonts` installed, that suffices for `fontspec`, but there is more math support if you also install `libertinus-otf` and `libertinus-math`.

Comment: I am using Minion font. If I am using minion font accents character clashing with each other. Could you please explain how to define single character with multiple accents in minion font.